# How to correctly configure HttpClient's streaming for large files?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Microsoft's official documentation for [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) states that if we'd like to use HttpClient to download large files, we should

> stream those downloads and not use the default buffering. If the default buffering is used the client memory usage will get very large, potentially resulting in substantially reduced performance.

What's the default buffering, and how do we change it, so that we won't have problems hitting the outlined problem above, regardless of the file size we end up downloading?

A dummy code snippet would be highly appreciated!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.maxresponsecontentbuffersize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @RyanWilson that basically allows us to change the maximum download size, correct? I'm not sure that merely changing that to a high value would fix the issue. From what I understand the default buffering somehow impacts performance heavily. Does that mean content is stored in memory? If so, concurrent download requests could indeed drastically slow down our machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `GetStreamAsync` method. As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=netframework-4.8):

> This operation will not block. The returned Task object will complete after the response headers are read. **This method does not read nor buffer the response body**.

example:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var requestUri = "http://url-to-resource.com";
var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri);

using (var fileStream = File.Create("outputFile.ext"))
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

All the other methods like `GetByteArrayAsync` or `GetStringAsync` will buffer the response and will complete after the whole response body is read.

The default buffer size used by `CopyToAsync` is 81920 bytes as declared by [_DefaultCopyBufferSize](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,131). You can change it by using the overload `CopyToAsync(Stream, Int32)`.