# Limit the use of bandwith for the download using httpclient

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a question about file downloads. I would like to understand how large file downloads work in .Net HttpClient.

Lets say I have file of size 1GB. When I send a HTTP GET request to download the file from a HttpClient, using `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` method, does it retrieve the response body (byte by byte) as I read or does it retrieves the full response as and buffer on the client?

I'm asking this because I want to understand if I can limit the use of bandwith for the download on the client.

Thanks.

Comment: It reads N bytes from the Stream at a time. How many specifically is dependent on the reader using the stream.

Comment: Is this your anwser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326466/how-to-correctly-configure-httpclients-streaming-for-large-files

Comment: But the question remains whether the packets are retrieved when and if the stream is read (so if I throttle the reading, the network bandwith I use would be throttled too), or the packets arrive independently to the NIC and are buffered somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No sir, its not possible I think, But you can use `HttpClient.Timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the size of the file that you are downloading before the download begins. you can add a condition based on your bandwidth limit if the client can download this file or not.